# A sticky broadcast intent for a bluetooth headset in android/or an alternative

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-broadcast, headset, sticky-broadcast

I am working on a app where I require to know if there is a bluetooth headset connected. I have created a broadcast receiver that receives the broadcast intents if we connect to the bluetooth headset while the app is on. on the other hand if a connect to the bluetooth device and then start the app I do not receive any broadcast for the bluetooth device connection. I would like to know if any bluetooth headset is connected on the app start. following is my broadcast receiver and manifest.

```
public class BluetoothDeviceConnectionReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    static OnBluetoothDeviceStateChangeLisener onBluetoothStateChangedListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    //int headsetAudioState = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.headset.extra.AUDIO_STATE", -2);

    //Toast.makeText(context, "New Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    Log.i("headsetAudioState","in broadcast");


    if (BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        int bluetoothHeadsetState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_STATE,
                BluetoothHeadset.STATE_DISCONNECTED);
        Log.i("headsetAudioState",bluetoothHeadsetState+" ");
        //Device found
        if (bluetoothHeadsetState == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            if (onBluetoothStateChangedListener != null)
                onBluetoothStateChangedListener.OnBluetoothHeadsetConnected();
            Log.i("headsetAudioState",bluetoothHeadsetState+" connected");
        }
        if(bluetoothHeadsetState == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_DISCONNECTED){
            if (onBluetoothStateChangedListener != null)
                onBluetoothStateChangedListener.OnBluetoothHeadsetDisconnected();
            Log.i("headsetAudioState",bluetoothHeadsetState+" disconnected");
        }
    }



    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        //Device is now connected
        if (onBluetoothStateChangedListener != null)
            onBluetoothStateChangedListener.OnBluetoothHeadsetConnected();
    } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
        //Done searching
    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
        //Device is about to disconnect
    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        //Device has disconnected
        if (onBluetoothStateChangedListener != null)
            onBluetoothStateChangedListener.OnBluetoothHeadsetDisconnected();

    } 


    }
    public void setOnBluetoothStateChangeListener(OnBluetoothDeviceStateChangeLisener listener){
    onBluetoothStateChangedListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnBluetoothDeviceStateChangeLisener{
    void OnBluetoothHeadsetConnected();
    void OnBluetoothHeadsetDisconnected();
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
   .....
   .....
   .....

   <receiver android:name=".BluetoothDeviceConnectionReciver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

   .....
   .....
```

I would like to know if there are any other intents that i should be listening to. Or please let me know what other options I have to achieve the intended goal.

P.S : the device connected should be a headset as I intend to use the mic of the bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I digged a lot but wasn't able to find any broadcast that is sticky so that on the start of app I would get to know if the phone is connected to bluetooth headset as mentioned in the question.

The work arround that I implemented is to get the bluetooth adapter and check the connection status of the bluetooth profile as in the below code

```
    public boolean isBluetoothHeadsetConnected() {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        boolean isConnected = mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()
                && mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED;
        Log.i("bluetoothConnected",isConnected+"");
        return  isConnected;
    }
```

I call this code in `onCreate()` of the `SplashScreenActivity` of the app and set the corresponding flag. The changes in the bluetooth state after app start are then taken care by the Broadcast listeners that i have implemented as in the question. This code served my purpose very well.

Comment: Using this code not able to distinguish between Android watch or bluetooth headest, is there any way to distnguish between this two.